# Convert year in buddhist format

Tags: angularjs

I'm newbie AngularJS and have question. I use `Date.now()` for create current time. But I want display year in Buddhist format. I use code from this topic -> [How to make a ticking clock (time) in AngularJS and HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23383233/how-to-make-a-ticking-clock-time-in-angularjs-and-html). How I can convert year to Buddhist format ? Thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need a filter something like this:-

```
    myapp.filter('bdate', function($filter)
    {
     return function(input)
     {
      if(input == null){ return ""; } 
      var bYears=500;
      //Please write the formula for getting the buddhist date here
      //Below is a rough conversion of adding 365*bYears days to todays date

     // Convert 'days' to milliseconds
        var millies = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365 * bYears;
     var d = new Date(input).getTime()+millies;
      var _date = $filter('date')(new Date(d), 'MMM dd yyyy');

      return _date.toUpperCase();

     };
    });
```

Usage of above filter is as below:-

```
 <span>{{dt | bdate}}</span>
```

Check the code working at [Plunkr here](http://plnkr.co/edit/MDakNpNDkr9Fnxqk6zaw?p=preview).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks guy. Now I use moment.js and add year 543 with now date. I great too. thanks for you answer again. ;)

Comment: If the date is something like '29/02/2016' (leap year), you'll get '1/03/2562' because 29/02/2562 doesn't exist, because 2562 is not a leap year and 28 Feb is the last day. And that issue is the same with momentjs, because moment js is using new Date(). Try moment('29/02/2016'), and you'll get an invalid date.