# AngularJS date mask

Tags: angularjs-directive

What would be my best options using AngularJS for a date mask on an input field? I have tried using ui-mask="99/99/9999" but it is not parsing the string correctly that the Date object is returning. Any suggestions?

Edit:

I am using BreezeJs to retrieve the date for the vm.worksheet.date model. The object associated with that model is a Date object. When  it pulls in a date like 01/27/2014, the input field gets updated to 27/20/1402. ui-mask is trying to parse the date string in the form of "Mon Jan 27 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)". It also throws an error: Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!

Comment: add more info as to what you have tried and the error you're getting when its not parsing :)

Comment: An example to this question has been provided [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35323265/4775223)