# Angular function not working?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to Angular but I've done a couple basic examples successfully. Now I'm looking at starting my first real world Angular/MVC/WebAPI app. It's going to be a Time Card type app and the first thing I'm looking to do is display the current time of the local user. I did to a basic HelloWorld with Angular on the Index.cshtml page just to make sure my references to Angular were correct. That worked....BTW, I'm using Angular v1.5.

I found the following post and I'm trying to use a mixture of the code.

```
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/806029/Getting-started-with-AngularJS-and-ASP-NET-MVC-Par

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23383233/how-to-make-a-ticking-clock-time-in-angularjs-and-html
```

However I'm not getting it to work and it's probably something simple I'm missing, yet I don't see it.

Here is my _Layout.csthml. I have the ng-app and ng-controller listed in the 
`<html>` tag

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="VirtualTimeClockApp" ng-controller="LandingPageController">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")

</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                @Html.ActionLink("Application name", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                </ul>
                @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/angular")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/VirtualTimeClockApp")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)

</body>
</html>
```

Here is my Home/Index.cshtml

```
@model VirtualTimeClock.ViewModels.HomeViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>@Model.currentServerTime</h1>

    <div ng-controller='TimeCtrl'>
        <p>{{ clock | date:'HH:mm:ss'}}</p>
    </div>

    <p class="lead">ASP.NET is a free web framework for building great Web sites and Web applications using HTML, CSS and JavaScript.</p>
    <p><a href="http://asp.net" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
</div>
```

Here is my BundleConfig.cs file. Next to the last Bundles.Add is where I bundle the controller directory and the main .js file.

```
namespace VirtualTimeClock
{
    public class BundleConfig
    {
        // For more information on bundling, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301862
        public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                      "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/angular").Include(
                      "~/Scripts/angular.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/VirtualTimeClockApp")
                    .IncludeDirectory("~/Scripts/Controllers", "*.js")
                    .Include("~/Scripts/VirtualTimeClock.js"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                      "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                      "~/Content/site.css"));
        }
    }
}
```

This is my VirtualTimeClock.js file. The thing I'm not 100% on here is the declaration of VirtrualTimeClockApp is then adding a module to the "VirtualTimeClockApp" that is referenced in the ?

```
var VirtualTimeClockApp = angular.module('VirtualTimeClockApp', []);

VirtualTimeClockApp.controller('LandingPageController', LandingPageController);
```

This is my LandingPageController.js file.

```
var module = angular.module('VirtualTimeClockApp', []);

module.controller('TimeCtrl', function ($scope, $interval) {
    var tick = function () {
        $scope.clock = Date.now();
    }
    tick();
    $interval(tick, 1000);
});
```

Comment: Are you getting any erros in the console and when you look at the page source, check the order that the scripts are being called - it might be calling `LandingPageController.js` before `VirtualTimeClock.js`

Comment: @christiandev....No errors that I can see. It just displays {{ clock | date:'HH:mm:ss'}} in the page. So something is not tied together correctly.

Comment: You define a `LandingPageController` but i do not see the function you are referring to. There should be a `function LandingPageController(){};` in your code somewhere.

Comment: @KreepN....again, I'm still learning but in the VirtualTimeClock.js file it creates a controller called 'LandingPageController' and I'm assuming the next property is the LandingPageController.js even though it just says LandingPageController. Then in LandingPageController.js file has a function aliased by 'TimeCtrl' will calls the function to set the $scope.clock to the current date. At least that's the way I'm understanding it.

Comment: @Caverman `I'm assuming the next property is the LandingPageController.js` is a wrong assumption. The second parameter is the function name, which you have not defined. Angular does not load JS files from controllers like that.

Comment: http://www.disposablechat.com/chat/AngularTime?password=

Comment: I followed the example below and got the LandingPageController to work. I'll have to look over the code again. I've got a virtual course I need to go through again to see if it will help me figure it out. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/806029/Getting-started-with-AngularJS-and-ASP-NET-MVC-Par

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your VirtualTimeClock.js to...

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('VirtualTimeClockApp', []);
})();

(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('VirtualTimeClockApp')
        .controller('LandingPageController', LandingPageController);


    function LandingPageController() {

    }
})();
```

and the other file to:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('VirtualTimeClockApp')
        .controller('TimeCtrl', TimeCtrl);

    TimeCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$interval'];

    function TimeCtrl($scope, $interval) {
        var tick = function () {
            $scope.clock = Date.now();
        }
        tick();
        $interval(tick, 1000);
    }
})();
```

and reorder the bundle...

```
 bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/VirtualTimeClockApp")
                    .Include("~/Scripts/VirtualTimeClock.js")
                    .IncludeDirectory("~/Scripts/Controllers", "*.js")
                    );
```

[image]

I think the main issue was the bundle order, but it's cleaner to use [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression).   Also, worth reading this [style guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md).

Comment: BINGO! with a small change. I used your code initially but it wasn't working (even though I think it should have been). Then I decided that I wanted the controller to work in a specific section of the page and not the every page that I'm going to build. So I moved ng-controller="LandingPageController" from the HTML tag in the _Layout.cshtml page to the <div class="jumbotron"> which is where I want this piece of angular to work. Then it started working. Thanks for the help! I'm sure there will be other questions coming soon.

Comment: @Caverman, moving the placement lower in the dom shouldn't make any difference - I think it was the bundling.  Either way, check out that style guide, it really helped me when starting out. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the brackets from here

```
var VirtualTimeClockApp = angular.module('VirtualTimeClockApp',[]);
```

And create a function called LandingPageController. It should look like this:

```
var VirtualTimeClockApp = angular.module('VirtualTimeClockApp');

VirtualTimeClockApp.controller('LandingPageController',   LandingPageController);

function LandingPageController() {}
```

If you use the brackets you are creating a new module, which in this case is already created on your *LandingPageController.js* file

---

Comment: @Sergio....thanks for the suggestion. I removed the brackets but it's still not working. I'll leave the brackets off. There were in the sample code I pulled from one of the links above. I now have "var module = angular.module('VirtualTimeClockApp');" in my LandingPageController.js file.

Comment: @Caverman I updated the answer. I got confused with the names earlier. The was two issues, the LandingPageController function was not defined, and also the brackets ;)