# Integrating HTML and AngularJS for a digital clock

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying to learn HTML/CSS and AngularJS by making a single-page web app that will show time, weather, and other info. My goal is to be able to drag and drop these on the web page so that a user can arrange them as they see fit.

My first step is to show time, which I'm able to do (I got the code [based on this code from another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23383233/how-to-make-a-ticking-clock-time-in-angularjs-and-html)). However, it doesn't actually work on my own environment and I'm not sure if it's because my files are incorrectly linked. My directory structure looks something like this:

```
-- app
   + -- clock.js
-- node_modules 
-- public (holds css and images)
index.html
(some other files)
```

As you can see in my code, I wrote `<script src="app/clock.js"></script>`, but when I check localhost:8080, instead of the time, I get {{ clock | date 'HH:mm:ss' }}. Is there something else I need to include in the html or js file to get Angular to start working?

```js
var app = angular.module('test_app', []);

app.controller('updateClock', function($scope, $interval) {
  var tick = function() {
    $scope.clock = Date.now();
  }
  tick();
  $interval(tick, 1000);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>TEST PAGE</title>

  <link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
  <script src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.11/angular.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div ng-app="test_app">
    <div class="container">
      <div ng-controller='updateClock'>
        <p>{{ clock | date: 'HH:mm:ss'}}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
<script src="app/clock.js"></script>

</html>
```

**Edited to add server code:**

```
// server.js

// using express
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var port = 8080;

// route the app
var router = require("./app/routes")
app.use("/", router);

// set static files (css, images, etc)
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))

// start the server
app.listen(port,function() {
  console.log('Live at port ' + port);
});
```

Comment: Does your browser's dev tools show any error messages? It sounds like the path to the Javascript file is probably incorrect when run using a web server. Try changing it to `/app/clock.js`

Comment: EDIT: Sorry, I answered too quickly. I tried changing it to `/app/clock.js` and I get a message saying, "TypeError: this.transport is null."

Comment: It should probably work if you just straight up open your index.html in a browser.

Comment: @geofrey: I used Node.js to set up a server and have been typing localhost:8080 to check the view. Is there some other what I should be looking at index.html directly? This is the first time I've done web development.

Comment: Your code is working properly. Check this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/81lnN39Lq98Wj3G5ndyH

Comment: Googling that error suggests [it's something that's specific to Firefox on Ubuntu](http://git.net/ml/ubuntu-bugs/2015-10/msg03036.html). Any chance you can try it in Chrome? That way we can see if it's browser-specific.

Comment: @WaldirJ.PereiraJunior Thanks for verifying the code is working. However, the clock doesn't show up on my browser when I test it on my environment/browser.

Comment: @sarah if you're just playing around with front-end stuff like angular, just do a "File -> open file" in your browser and open index.html file, you probably don't need a backend nodejs server at this point.

Comment: The version of Angular you're loading is super old. I would recommend trying the latest 1.x version of Angular and see if it resolves your issues. Everything looks in order and runs properly here. You may be running into a Firefox specific issue that's already been fixed. Try loading Angular from here: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js

Comment: @geofrey If I open index.html, it shows the clock, but it doesn't show any of the CSS stuff I did for testing. Is that normal?

Comment: @MatthewDaly I have the same issue on Chrome, where I see "{{ clock | date: 'HH:mm:ss'}}" instead of an actual clock. I got two errors: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)" (referring to clock.js) and "Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.4/$injector/modulerr?p0=test_app&p1=Error%3…ogleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.6.4%2Fangular.min.js%3A22%3A179)"

Comment: @MikeFeltman I updated the Angular version. Based on your and other's comments, I know the issue isn't the code; for some reason, index.html can't access where clock.js is.

Comment: It sounds like the path to the files is your problem. If your web root is something like `www/` and your HTML file is `www/index.html`, your Javascript file would have to be at `www/app/clock.js` to be found.

Comment: @MatthewDaly It's exactly as you wrote: my root is myFolder, so index.html is in myFolder/index.html. The folder app is in myFolder, so clock is in myFolder/app/clock.js. I'm not sure why index.html can't see clock.js. You can see the directory structure I listed in my original question.

Comment: You would probably need to change the path to your css file relative to where index.html. According to your dir structure, your link ref to your css should be: <link href="public/.../style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

Comment: the MIME type error is probably related how you're serving your static files (probably being served as text/html by default). If you'd still like to resolve your server error, it might help to post your nodejs server code as well. But if you're only experimenting on front-end just opening index.html in browser should be enough.

Comment: It can't see it because it's outside the web root. If you copy the `app/` folder into `public/` (not just the files but the whole folder) it should be able to find the file.

Comment: @geofrey In my server.js, I used `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))` to set my static files. As a result, in index.html, I simply use `<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`

Is this affecting my reference to clock.js somehow? But clock.js isn't necessarily a static file.

Comment: @MatthewDaly Can you clarify why `index.html` can only see files in `public/`? Shouldn't it be able to see the files in `app/` as well since it's at the root and all other files are in inside other folders?

Comment: It'll depend on the settings for the server you're using, but if you are viewing the HTML at localhost:8080, that implies the folder that index.html is in is your web root. It therefore won't see the Javascript files if they are outside that folder.

Comment: I note that you're using Express and your static directory is the public one. That means that is the web root for static files.

Comment: @MatthewDaly I added my server.js code to my question. Do I have to put my JS files inside the public folder then? How can I structure my directory or my code so that I can organize the JS code?

Comment: Yes, any JS for the client side must be inside the static folder

Comment: @MatthewDaly Some other tutorials I've seen have put their JS files in a JS folder (outside of `/public`). Is that for "dynamic" files? Or do I have to change my code in server so that it knows to look in folders besides `/public`?

Comment: Static files would need to be served from the folder set as the static folder in Express. That doesn't mean the source files necessarily as you could be using something like Webpack to process them, but the actual JS files you need to serve must be in that static folder