# i want to rewrite code in javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to rewrite Javascript code in simple way. Could anyone help me on how to simplify this code? I need a clearer implementation using  AngularJS. Need some advice how to rewrite the code:

```
function startTime() {
            var today = new Date();
            var D = today.getDate();
            var M = today.getMonth() + 1;
            var Y = today.getFullYear();
            var h = today.getHours();
            var m = today.getMinutes();
            var s = today.getSeconds();
            // add a zero in front of numbers<10
            m = checkTime(m);
            s = checkTime(s);

            if (document.getElementById('time'))
            {
            document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = Y + "-"+ M + "-"+ D + " "+ h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
            t = setTimeout(function () {
                startTime();
            }, 50);
            }
        }
        startTime();
```

This above code is pure Javascript code but I want to write code in AngularJS. I'm just looking for a little advice on how to rewrite code using Javascript and AngularJS.

Comment: which version of angular are you using and can you post what you have tried so far?

Comment: Javascript date formatting can't be simplified all that much. What I'd suggest is using a library like momentjs to handle date/time stuff. As for AngularJs, no-one can answer how to rewrite this using angular. (which would in any case only be relevant for displaying the time in the browser, not the date formatting part). Is suggest you do some Angular tutorials and come back with a *specific* question.

Comment: @seesharper angularjs' dateFilter will handle formatting stuff

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32137013/7404943). I left timeout 1000, if you see the need you can change if back to 50 as in your code.

```js
var module = angular.module('app', []);

module.controller('TimeCtrl', function($scope, $interval) {
  var tick = function() {
    $scope.time = Date.now();
  }
  tick();
  $interval(tick, 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller='TimeCtrl'>
    <p ng-bind="time | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```