# I want to refresh or reload the $scope evey 60 secs

Tags: angularjs, hash, timeout, refresh, apply

`````
Hi I am learning angularjs.
The main idea is to "refesh" or "reload" the $scope.
I was able to refresh the page with this ```location.reload();````.
But i was recomended to refresh the $scope, not the hole page.
I reserached about this, I reckon I should use apply or digest.
As so far the code is like this:
`````

### refresh.component.js

```
    myApp.component('refreshComponent', {
        template:"<button class='btn btn-lg btn-info text-uppercase' ng-click='vm.refresh()'Refresh </button>",
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        controller: function RefreshController($scope, $element, $attrs) {
           vm = this;

          vm.refresh = function(){
            location.reload();
          }
        }
      });
```

As I understand this should change:(this are assumptions, I dont know, if I sould keep the component or refactor into a controller or somthing else, it is not clear to me)

1. The button should not longer exist, so it will be automatically
   refreshing avery 60 secs.
2. The component should not longer exist.
3. I have an utils.js, where I suppose I should place the next code:

   ```
   setTimeout($scope.apply(), 60000);
   setTimeout($scope.digest(), 60000);
   ```

I dont know, if I am using apply or diggest in the correct way

Comment: What is your reasoning for running a regular digest cycle? If you want to update your data in the view do so by assigning your data to the $scope in your controller. There are times when calling $apply() or $digest() are appropriate, but without more information, I’ll say what you are attempting is probably not good practice.

Comment: Hi Juan. I would say in general you shouldn't have to trigger a digest cycle because angularjs is pretty good at doing that for you assuming what you are doing is within the context of angular. There are some events that can happen outside of angular's knowledge that could require a manual trigger but I would say those are the exception, not the rule. Like tbone mentioned its a little hard to give good advice without more context, can you give us a bit more information about what it is exactly you're trying to refresh?

Comment: Ok, I understand a little bit more, about this pratice.
I already display a few components: Date&Time, Greetings Sentece, Weather and Dark Theme.
It seems Those compoents should be updated by the current hour (getHour(); from Date object).
So the idea is to update the $scope of each component from one function

Comment: I found several exmpales, about update the $scope with $timeout and $interval, where it updates her $scope, but i dont undestand how to update all the $scope at once.
for eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23383233/how-to-make-a-ticking-clock-time-in-angularjs-and-html